# Ansible Playbook- Pass variables in for loop

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create tomcat cluster based on number of hosts, and I am trying to pass variables to a for loop in template file.

I want to control `num_hosts` from variables.

The template file snippet is:

```
{% for id in range(1,( {{ num_hosts }} )) %}
    <Member
       className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
       port="4110"
       host="${test.server.web.other{{ id }}.fqdn}"
       domain="delta-static"
    />
{% endfor %}
```

Got the below error

```
fatal: [test-web01.aliceapp.com]: FAILED! =>
{"changed": false,
"failed": true,
"invocation": {"module_args": {"dest": "/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat/conf/server.xml", "src": "test/server.j2"}, "module_name": "template"},
"msg": "AnsibleError: an unexpected type error occurred. Error was an integer is required"}
```

I have tried multiple combination of syntaxes, bot none of them are working.

Comment: please include the part of the playbook you are using here as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to make it work with following syntax.

{% for id in range(1, ( num_hosts|int ) ) %}

Answer (score 3):

`range` accespts integers as it's parameters, but jinja will be default convert everything to string. You can use the `int` built in jinja2 filter to convert values to integer:

```
{% for id in range(1,( {{ num_hosts | int }} )) %}
```